# Creating an array of unlike objects

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

This is a followup to my last question wherein I need an array of objects which are child classes of one base class. I was suggested I try dynamic_cast but speed is very important in this project.

Here is essentially what I am after.

```
class Object
{
protected:
    int id;
};

class Bike: public Object
{
public:
    bike();

private:
    int bells;
};

class Car: public Object
{
public:
    void drive();

private:
    int wheels;
};
```

I need an array of these objects so I decided to use the base class.

```
// Imagine I have 10 objects and don't know what they will be
Object* objects[10];

// Let's make the first object
objects[0] = new Car;
```

I was told dynamic casting was a good idea. The problem is that speed is important and I have instances where I will need to do such operations as:

1. Car 8 references a bike at index value 3.

Is there any other workaround without dynamic_casting?

EDIT: If I populated the array with a bunch of child classes, how could I access the data of a child class at a specific index. In other words, imagine a bike is at index 8. How could I get the int bells from that object with just the array and index.

Comment: Habe you actually measured a performance problem with a `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: Why do you need to cast? When you are holding them in an array, I assume that you want to call some polymorphic method on the elements in that array without the need to know the exact type of those objects. If not, I don't get your actual use case to store objects of different types in a single array!

Comment: @Vikdor If I populate the array with child classes and let's say at index 5, which let's say is a car, it wants me to access a bike which let's say is at index 3. How do I access the child class at index 3? In other words, get at the data from the child class at a specific index. Keep in mind it's an array of base classes. Why doesn't C++ just support this?

Comment: FWIW, from your reply and without more background about the use case,  I just don't understand how would the object of a child class give me the index of another object in an array. My gut feeling is that this approach of storing objects of different types is just incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what else you're doing, but you could have an array of structures that store an enumeration that specifies what object type it's storing along with an object pointer.

IE:

```
class CObject;

enum EObjectType
{
    OT_Bike,
    OT_Car
};

struct SObjectInfo
{
    EObjectType Type;
    CObject* Object;
};
```

When iterating through your array, you can check the type of the object, then *static* cast the object pointer to the appropriate derived type. I use this approach extensively where it can't be avoided and run-time identification of an object type is absolutely necessary within a generic container.

Why do you need to store objects of different classes in the same array, though, without using polymorphism and virtual methods?

Comment: Because some objects reference others by index. Not in the example, but in the project I am working on, they do.

Answer (score 0):

If the Objects are unlike, why have a base class?
This link might be of help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23304/High-Performance-Heterogeneous-Container

Comment: They are all alike in that they have the same base data (an master index and a string) and then everything else is different. The problem is that some of these objects reference one another. So I need a quick way to access them.

Comment: You should consider the API how you want to access the data of each class involved. Instead of inheritance, use a plain struct for the common data or a std::tuple.

I've tried your classes with tek (adding a dummy method cycle in the bike). Here's what it would look like

        tek::record< Bike, Car > Objects;
        Objects.get<0>().cycle();
        Objects.get<1>().drive();

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you need it to be very fast do not create it on the heap with operator new. You need to create them locally if possible.

If you are sure that there will be always your objects than you can change casting to static_cast which is a lot of faster solution.

For me the best idea here is to use  Interfaces with pure virtual methods. like:

```
Class Objects //interface
{
public:
   virtual void ride() = 0;
}
```

and then use a interface as a base class. It is very common in the programming.

Comment: That's fine but it's not what I am after. If I need to get at the data in the child class say at index 7 after the array has been populated, how is this possible without dynamic_cast?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that your problem requires some run-time overhead, no matter how the implementation would look: this is because at some point the program needs to decide what type it actually stores. Note that you have more alternatives to introducing a bit artificial inheritance, provided you can afford using Boost:

- [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/variant.html) - if you know all the types that you will be storing in advance
- [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/any.html) - if you do not